# WCF error with enum collection

Tags: c#, wcf, collections, enums

This program works fine with simple enum.
But when I want a collection of enum there is a WCF error when I launch it.

```
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(ErrorData))]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "TestEnum?productRetrieveOptions={productRetrieveOptions}")]
    string TestEnum(ICollection<DTO.ProductRetrieveOption> productRetrieveOptions);



    public string TestEnum(ICollection<DTO.ProductRetrieveOption> productRetrieveOptions)
    {
        return string.Format("OK ({0})", productRetrieveOptions);
    }



[DataContract]
public enum ProductRetrieveOption : int
{
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    //[EnumMember]
    Stock = 0,

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    //[EnumMember]
    RightAssociated = 1,

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    //[EnumMember]
    ValidityDate = 2,

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    //[EnumMember]
    FullTariff = 3,
}
```

The error is :

Operation 'TestEnum' contract Isale has a request variable named 'productRetrieveOptions' type' System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1 [DTO.ProductRetrieveOption] ', but the type' System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1 [DTO.ProductRetrieveOption] 'is not convertible with' QueryStringConverter '. The variables for UriTemplate query values must have types that can be converted by 'QueryStringConverter'.

I tried with IList, [], IEnumarable and ICollection, and Ialways got the same kind of error.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your own version of the `QueryStringConverter`. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/08/08/wcf-extensibility-querystringconverter/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In fact we can use complex types but we have to use POST and nothing in uritemplate

Answer (score 0):

Finaly it was quite basic error

```
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(ErrorData))]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "TestEnum")]
    string TestEnum(ICollection<DTO.ProductRetrieveOption> productRetrieveOptions);
```